# Cannot create IOS archive: Path (directory name must be less than 248 characters) and/or file name (must be less than 260 characters) are too long

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios, windows-10

**ERROR**

Cannot create IOS archive 'MyIosProject'. Process cannot be executed on XMA server. There was an error unzipping the file `C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Xamarin\iOS\Archives\2020-04-08\ac002825.zip`: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED SO FAR**

1. Enable long file name support in Windows 10
   Start the registry editor (regedit.exe)
   Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem.
   Double click LongPathsEnabled.
   Set to 1 and click OK.
   Reboot.
2. Hit the Windows key, type gpedit.msc and press Enter.
   Navigate to Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem > NTFS.
   Double click the Enable NTFS long paths option and enable it.
   If you're using a version of Windows that does not provide access to Group Policy, you can edit the registry instead.
   Reboot.
3. Add this to your .csproj file: `<PropertyGroup><UseShortFileNames>True</UseShortFileNames></PropertyGroup>`

None of the above solved my issue.

Comment: Why the -1 without any comment?

Comment: I think it's because it's a very common Visual Studio error. It seems to have a different solution for Xamarin Developers but the Question reviewers didn't take that into consideration. Don't worry about it, but you can probably avoid the negative points by specifying that you already tried the solutions provided in the other questions but those didn't work, and provide some links to those too :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**UPDATE:** you can now specify this directory in Visual Studio under `Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> iOS Settings -> Archives`. I have changed this path to: `C:\Users\myusername\0`

[image]

I had to update all my NuGet packages. Deleted obj and bin folders, restored nuget packages for the solution and rebuilded my project and on Windows also had to delete all IntermediateOutputPath in my csproj file of iOS project.

Comment: You can mark it later which will help more people with same problem:).

Comment: Mark what? As the "accepted answer"? I need to wait 23 more hours for that.