# Xamarin Extractions Temp Path, can this be changed?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, msbuild

Is it possible to set the path that Xamarin uses when Archiving app builds for it's "Extractions" path, I'm hitting a limitation with the windows maximum path length currently (And have setup group policy/regedit flags already to support longer lengths, that isn't helping).

Currently it seems to be set to `%APPDATA%\Local\Temp\Xamarin\Extractions\[GUID]\[Appname] [DateTime]\Products\Applications\[AppName]\[Component]` (or something like that anyway)

Is there an option / flag / setting in Visual Studio, MSBuild, or Xamarin somewhere that I can add to set that initial path from `%APPDATA%\Local\Temp\Xamarin\Extractions` to something shorter like `C:\Temp` ?

With my windows login name the path upto & including `Extractions` is already 63 characters of the 260 odd that are allowed, The `[GUID]` to the final folder part is another 146, so that really doesn't leave any room for the actual components themselves to be extracted / read from.

Not sure if it's relevant/helpful but I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2022 on Windows 10, the iOS builds are done via a networked Mac Mini but they won't even get that far anymore because of the archive process failing.

Also, the actual error I'm getting is: `There was an error unzipping the file C:\Development\Archives\iOS\2022-04-29\d921bd55.zip: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\... etc`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61120063/8395242

Comment: @Andrew That's for setting the archive path, which I've already done in the above example you'll see it's going to `C:\Development\Archives` it's the intermediate path that Xamarin itself extracts the various packages to in order to archive them that's the issue, specifically the `Temp\Xamarin\Extractions` path

Comment: Did you come up with a fix for this? I am experiencing something very similar.

Comment: I'm totally blocked with this very same issue. I tried changing the windows registry to allow long paths but didn't have any effect

Comment: As a workaround, you can change the TEMP and TMP environment variables from C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Temp to C:\tmp (Don't forget to restart your PC, this is needed...) 
In my case, reducing these few characters allowed me to complete the archiving process.

Comment: I ended up having to compile and archive the code on the mac mini itself as a work around, I've not tried again recently though as I've been on other non-xamarin projects. The temporary path workaround seems like it should help but does seem a bit overkill!